# How does the resolution of a stepper motor affect its performance?

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm looking at purchasing some stepper motors for a project of mine.

I found two which seem to be the same, except one has a 1.8 degree step and the other has a 0.9 degree step.

Now the application I want to add them to is a screw rod, not a belt-drive. I already have a fair amount of gear ratio in my favor. I really do not need such a low resolution, but that led me to think how does the resolution effect the performance of the motor in regards to:

- Torque,
- Speed,
- Acceleration

Links:

- https://www.robotics.org.za/datasheet/42BYGHM809.PDF (0.9)
- https://www.robotics.org.za/datasheet/MR42BYGHW804_datasheet.pdf (1.8)

Comment: How about a link to the motors in question? Usually there are torque/speed curves and other useful data. You question is a bit like saying I've found a car that is has 18" tires and one that has 16" tires, which will have better performance or fuel economy? It's even possible that the motors are the same and one is specified differently from (BrE: to) the other.

Comment: I am not only asking in regard to these motors specifically. I was more asking in a general term. Just the theory behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, your question concerns a hypothetical: *if* only step size changes, then what happens to the other characteristics? There are a lot of variables in motor design.

Here's one example of speed-torque curves, from one major Japanese manufacturer ([Oriental Motor](http://www.orientalmotor.com/technology/articles/article-speed-torque-curves-for-step-motors.html)), showing some differences where the main distinction is the step size (orange curve vs. black dashed curve):

[image]

Comment: OK so according to the graph, the 0.9 degree will have less torque in general. However another aspect I want to know it maximum speed. Cause surely the 0.9 will have twice as many steps to achieve the same speed.

Comment: Assume a torque required and compare RPMs.  Below 500 RPM it's better to have 0.9 deg steps.